# Angular JS page with more than 10 search options

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular JS and I am creating a html page where it has more than 12 search options available to the user .

Now should I create 12 separate functions to call the REST API to fetch the search data,is there a better way we can handle this.

I would also like to know if there are no search results found should i keep the user on the same page  or take them to next page and display no items found ?

How can I implement this I am using angular `ui-router` to go between the pages.

I would also like to know how can i go about displaying something like search in progress (loading image) when user clicks on some button .

thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Can you share html view

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">          
        <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <form role="search">
                        <div  class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="searchQuery.name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" id="mobile-number" ng-model="searchQuery.mobileNumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="email" id="email" ng-model="searchQuery.emailId" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>
                        <div  class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="searchQuery.filter4" placeholder="filter4" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text"  ng-model="searchQuery.filter5" placeholder="filter5" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text"  ng-model="searchQuery.filter6" placeholder="filter6" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>          
                            </div>
                        <div  class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text"  ng-model="searchQuery.filter7" placeholder="filter7" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text"  ng-model="searchQuery.filter8" placeholder="filter8" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="searchQuery.filter9" placeholder="filter9" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>          
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text"  ng-model="searchQuery.filter10" placeholder="filter10" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="number" ng-model="searchQuery.filter11" placeholder="filter11" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text"  ng-model="searchQuery.filter12" placeholder="filter12" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>          
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                                <button class="btn btn-info" id="search" type="button" ng-click="search(searchQuery, 0)">
                                    Search
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                                <button class="btn btn-info" id="clear" type="button" ng-click="clearSearch()">
                                    Clear
                                </button>
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <loading></loading>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover" ng-show="!loading">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Mobile Number</th>
                            <th>Email Id</th>
                            <th>Address</th>                                
                            <th><a ng-click="sortBy('user.createdDate')">Added Date</a></th>
                            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="no-data" colspan="8" ng-show="itemList.length === 0">No Record found</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="user in itemList track by user.id">
                            <td>{{$index + index}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.fullName}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.mobileNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.emailId}}</td>                           
                            <td>{{user.address}}</td>                           
                            <td>{{user.createdDate |date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>                            
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        <pagination ng-show="!loading && totalItems > itemsPerPage" boundary-links="true" ng-change="pageChanged(currentPage)" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="10" class="pagination-sm" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;"></pagination>
    </div>
    </div>
```

SearchCtrl controller

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $state, orderByFilter, SearchFactory) {

    /**
     * Initialization
     */
    $scope.index = 1;
    $scope.pageTitle = 'Listing';
    $scope.searchQuery = {};
    $scope.searchQuery.pageSize = 50;
    $scope.searchQuery.pageNo = 0;
    $scope.itemList = [];
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 50;

    /**
     * Search
     * @param SearchQuery : Search object contains various values for search.
     * @param PageNo : Requesting data for particular page number .
     */
    $scope.search = function(searchQuery, pageNo) {
        searchQuery.pageNo = pageNo;
        $scope.loading = true;
        SearchFactory.get({'searchQuery':angular.toJson(searchQuery)}, function(response) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.itemList = response.items;
            $scope.itemsPerPage = response.pageSize;
            $scope.totalItems = response.count;
            $scope.searchQuery = searchQuery;
        }, function(e) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            console.error(e);
        });
    };
    /**
     * Load default item list
     */
    $scope.search($scope.searchQuery, 0);
    /**
     * Fetch data for selected page.
     */
    $scope.pageChanged = function (currentPage) {
        $scope.index = 1 + ($scope.searchQuery.pageSize * (currentPage - 1));
        $scope.searchQuery.pageNo = currentPage -1;
        $scope.search($scope.searchQuery, currentPage -1);
    };
    /**
     * Clear search parameters.
     */
    $scope.clearSearch = function () {
        $scope.index = 1;
        $scope.searchQuery = {};
        $scope.searchQuery.pageSize = 50;
        $scope.searchQuery.pageNo = 0;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.search($scope.searchQuery,0);
    };  
    /**
     * sort column
     * @param propertyName : Column name
     */
    $scope.sortBy = function(propertyName) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.propertyName === propertyName) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
        $scope.itemList = orderByFilter($scope.itemList, $scope.propertyName, $scope.reverse);
    };
});
```

loading directive

```
app.directive('loading', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace:true,
      template: '<div class="loading"><span> <img src="assets/images/spinner.gif" width="60" /></span></div>',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                if (val)
                    $(element).show();
                else
                    $(element).hide();
            });
      }
    };
});
```

ui-router state

```
state('app.user-search', {
            url: '/search',
            templateUrl: 'user/user-search.html',
            controller: 'SearchCtrl',           
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have one function and pass the value of all the searchbox in that function. It will increase the performance of your page. If no result found then you can hide the data div(where u r going to show data) and show a div of no data found.